# How to do a simple Get with an ApiKey authorization?

Tags: c#, rest, postman, restsharp

here is my problem

When I use PostMan to do my request, there is no problem.
I do the following steps :

- I add my URL (as a GET method)
- in the Authorization tab, I chose the "APIKey" tab then enter the value

And that's all ! when I Send my request, it works fine.

So I'm trying to do the same thing with RestSharp in a desktop Windows form application (using VS 2019).

Here is What I tried :

```
var client = new RestClient("https://MyURL");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "ApiKey MyAPI");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Is there something wrong here ?
It seems pretty simple but I always get the following error :

{"success": false, "detail": "Unauthorized. Authentication required."}

Thanks

**Edit solution ** The problem was only the / that I needed to add at the end of the url !

Comment: In your PostMan request, press the 'Code' button and it should show a cURL command with all the headers you are adding.  It Authorization on there? Does it match EXACTLY what you are doing?  Are you missing any headers?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark  or fiddler and compare the first request in postman with first request in c#.  Solution is to make headers in c# look like postman headers.  The default headers in c# are not the same as postman.

Comment: @Neil : ok.. I learned that there is a "Code" button to have my request in RestSharp code. So the answer is Yes, there is this : request.AddHeader("Authorization", "ApiKey MYKEY"); 
But I still get the same error.

Comment: @jdweng I tried using WireShark, but I can't get the information I want. 
Do you know what filter I can use to help me please?

Comment: Are there any other headers in the postman code that you haven't included in your C# code?

Comment: Are you seeing any SSL/TLS messages both in postman and c#?

Comment: Maybe you can add the solution as the answer to your own question.